# QToolButton and color

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm trying to make a simple design to select a color and I'm using a QToolButton to open a QColorDialog.
My problem is that I would like the QToolButton to be of the selected color but I've only suceeded to set the background color, which is not what I want.

Here is a picture:

[image]

My code:

```
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(m_couleur);
if (color.isValid()) m_couleur=color;
m_labelCouleur->setPalette(QPalette(m_couleur));
m_labelCouleur->setAutoFillBackground(true);
m_buttonCouleur->setPalette(QPalette(m_couleur));
m_buttonCouleur->setAutoFillBackground(true);
```

Basically I would like the QToolButton to look something like this:

[image]

edit: Can anyone explain to me why the website won't let me add "Hi everybody" at the beginning?

Comment: Does it need to be a QToolButton? I've done exactly what you want using a QPushButton.

Comment: @Anthony no, it doesn't need to be a QToolButton at all. As long as I can give it the dimension I want it's fine. What attributes of QPushButton did you use?

Comment: @Leo: While politeness is encouraged, I believe salutations such as you describe are considered fluff and, therefore, not encouraged. Think of StackOverflow as a huge database of high quality questions and answers instead of a support group for elderly woodworkers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(m_couleur);
QPixmap px(20, 20);
px.fill(color);
m_buttonCouleur->setIcon(px);
```

No CSS involved in this case is (for me ofcourse) big pro

Comment: I didn't think creating an icon for each color would be that easy. I chose your solution because it looks better: [link](http://imgur.com/wLJVv). webclectic's solution looked like this: [link](http://i.imgur.com/QQgSB.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`setStylesheet`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop) function in order to change the background color of your button

```
m_buttonCouleur->setStyleSheet(QString("QToolButton{ background: %1; }").arg(m_couleur.name()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done exactly that by using a QPushButton and setting its style sheet to the result from the color picker. I guess a tool button should probably be the same.

```
button->setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: %1; "
                              "border: 1px; "
                              "border-color: black; "
                              "border-style: outset;").arg(color.name()));
```

Comment: I did this:     `m_buttonCouleur->setStyleSheet("background-color: %1; border: 1px; border-color: black; border-style: outset;").arg(m_couleur.name());` but I have the error: `invalid use of 'void'`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Leo, My fault. It should have been a QString in order to use the `arg` function. Updated.

Comment: Thanks it works now but I've chosen the "create-an-icon-every-time" because it looks better and I prefer not to interfere with the StyleSheet as long as it's possible. Thank you for explaining why I was getting the error though.